# Hive: load gziped CSV from hdfs as read-only into a table

Tags: hive, computer-vision, gzip

I have an hdfs folder with many csv.gz within, all with the same schema. My customer needs to read the content of these tables  through Hive.

I tried to apply https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CompressedStorage . However it moves the file, whereas I need it to stay in its initial directory.

Another problem is that I should load each file one by one, I would rather create a table from the directory and not manage file individually.

I do not master Hive at all. Is his possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible via `Hive`. You can create an external table and reference the existing `HDFS` location containing the `gzip` files. The schema for the data should be specified during the table creation.

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_data 
      (
        column_1 int,
        column_2 string
      )
      LOCATION 'hdfs:///my_data_folder_with_gzip_files';
```

Comment: This solution seems working. But actually it doesn't, it may give wrong results on reading data from Hive Table.